# Comodo TrustLogo Wiping Out JS based pages

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I'm guessing this happens with.. many.. somewhat old-tech things like this, but I have a javascript only website based on backbone, and have shopping pages I'd like to get some validated badges on, case in point: [A Comodo Trustlogo][1]

Basically, when I follow the instructions, it completely wipes out the page, replacing the entire body with a white page and the logo itself, instead of kindly inserting itself into a div or whatnot.

Anyone have an idea on how to get it to inline properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with where you have placed your Comodo code. Where you've placed it, both `document.write` and `document.writeln` will destroy the page.

Move it to the top of the `<body>` element or whereever **in the `<body>` element** (not outside, not in `<head>`, not directly in `<html>` nor on the outside) you prefer.

Comment: The examples suck, i want to put it anywhere in the page, but apparently that's poorly supported.  Thanks!

Comment: I am having this issue with my React base site. Can't figure out how to make it work. They do use document.write that wipes out everything on the page. Any insight will be much appreciated.